# DateTime.date give me a full Date why?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need only the date from a DateTime class so I use DateTime.Date,
but it gives me a Full DateTime format, like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date.Date
```

give me:
+       date    {12/01/2016 00:00:00}   System.DateTime

I only need the:
date    {12/01/2016}

Comment: `12/01/2016` and `12/01/2016 00:00:00` are one and the same. If you want to write it as text, you simply write `date.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: Do you know, it is called **DateTime** for a reason

Comment: This is so duplicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`12/01/2016 00:00:00` is the same as `12/01/2016` as a *value*.

If you wanna get `12/01/2016` as a string representation, you can use [`.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring) method like;

```
var str = date.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you wanna get this `12/01/2016` as a `DateTime`, simply you *can't*. A `DateTime` instance *always* has date and time part. That's why you see it as `12/01/2016 00:00:00` on debugger *even* if you set it's time part to midnight.

Comment: what i need is to use with a sql query and is give me exption with this formt

Comment: @Tzahi **No**. You should _never_ use string representation of your `DateTime` values when you deal with database processes. Just pass your `DateTime` values directly to your [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @Tzahi, use *paremetrized* queries, do not hardcode: `where ... myField = @myDateParam ... `

Comment: @ Dmitry how to do this?